# Post form with ajax tab loading

Tags: php, ajax

I have a page with a POST form, when I submit the form the details are updated in a database.
And I have another page where I use AJAX TAB, which means I load the first page with AJAX, when I do this and use the Form, the details are not updated in the database.

I would appreciate help.

```
  <?php
        if( isset($_POST['newcst']) )
        {
            /*client add*/
                //getting post from user add form
            $c_name = $_POST['c_name']; 
            $c_adress = $_POST['c_adress'];
            $c_idnum = $_POST['c_idnum'];
            $c_phone = $_POST['c_phone'];
            $c_mail = $_POST['c_mail'];
        echo $c_num;

        //insert client into SQL
        $wpdb->insert('se_clients',array(
            'c_name' => $c_name,
            'c_adress' => $c_adress,
            'user_id'=>$cur_id, 
            'c_num'=>$c_idnum,
            'c_phone'=>$c_phone,
            'c_mail'=>$c_mail,
        ));
      }
     ?>



      <html>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="newcst">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <label>Full name:</label>
            <input type='text' name='c_name' /><br><br>
            <label>ID: </label>
            <input type='text' name='c_idnum' /><br><br>
            <label>PHONE:</label>
            <input type='text' name='c_phone' /><br><br>
            <label>ADRESS: </label>
            <input type='text' name='c_adress' /><br><br>
            <label>EMAIL: </label>
            <input type='text' name='c_mail' /><br><br>
            <input name="newcst" type="submit" value="create">
          </form>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Ajax tab:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav li a").click(function() {

        $("#ajax-content").empty().append("<div id='loading'><img src='http://wigot.net/project/wp-content/themes/projthem/vendor/images/loader.gif' alt='Loading' /></div>");
        $("#nav li a").removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        $.ajax({ url: this.href, success: function(html) {
            $("#ajax-content").empty().append(html);
            }
    });
    return false;
    });


     $("#ajax-content").empty().append("<div id='loading'><img src='http://wigot.net/project/wp-content/themes/projthem/vendor/images/loader.gif' alt='Loading' /></div>");
    $.ajax({ url: 'invoice', success: function(html) {
            $("#ajax-content").empty().append(html);
    }
    });

});
```

Comment: Where are your code attempts, so we can keep on them?

Comment: My mistake, i got it update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, you need to add the PHP code that is responsible for entering data to the database on the main page that contains the AJAX and not the page with the form itself.

Answer (score 0):

hover(), click(), bind(), on() and others works only after reloading page.
So you can use live()

**or**

```
$(document).on('click', 'element', function () {
   ...
});
```

Comment: As i understand. after posting a form its refresh the page. Anyway, it might not change something at the page but its still suppose to add the details to my database, is'nt it?

Comment: yes. try to watch networks and console all your post data to check.